# MySQL 5.7 in Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, mysql

I want to install Mysql 5.7 on Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian Jessie. When I execute the command `apt-get install mysql-server`, it installs version 5.5.

What do I need to do?

**Update**

I did every step in @Sapher answer, but didn't work.

```
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en_GB
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie/rpi Translation-en
Fetched 20.2 kB in 12s (1,596 B/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease
Unable to find expected entry 'mysql-apt-config/binary-armhf/Packages' in       
Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones      
used instead.
root@raspberrypi:~#  apt-get install mysql-server-5.7 -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mysql-server-5.7
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mysql-server-5.7'
root@raspberrypi:~#
```

Comment: You will likely need to compile from source to get the bleeding edge.

Comment: maybe can test teh command:
sudo apt-get install mysql-community-server_5.7 -y

Comment: @SteveRobillard: or use Arch

Comment: My Bad, I'm sorry. I did delete that wrong answer

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian Jesse is a Debian flavor of Linux, which takes a conservative approach to including new versions in the stable release. The advantage is that the libraries have been thoroughly tested and you're unlikely to have any problems. The disadvantage is you might not always be using the most recent release.

There are "testing" and "unstable" versions of Jesse that haven't been fully tested, but even "unstable" version of MySQL is 5.6. So, if you really need MySQL version 5.7, you'll have to download the source and compile it from scratch.

If the source depends on packages that you don't have in the stable release, and you must get them from "testing" or "unstable", it opens a can of worms as your version becomes a mixture of tested and untested packages that might or might not work with the rest of your applications.