# MySQL 5.7 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mysql, systemd

Because this did not work for me:
[MySQL 5.7 in Raspberry Pi 2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43287/mysql-5-7-in-raspberry-pi-2)

I installed MySQL from source, and now I have MySQL 5.7.11 installed under `/usr/local/mysql`.

I've never used `systemd`, so I don't know exactly how it works. Many tutorials say use 'something like this'. Right now I would just like to start mysql, but that's failing.

```
pi@raspberry3:~/bin $ sudo systemctl stop mysql
pi@raspberry3:~/bin $ sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.server.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql.server)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2016-03-29 15:33:17 UTC; 5s ago
  Process: 21277 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql.server stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 20735 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql.server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 29 06:29:40 raspberry3 mysql.server[20735]: Starting MySQL
Mar 29 06:29:40 raspberry3 mysql.server[20735]: Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe) ... failed!
Mar 29 06:29:40 raspberry3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop MySQL.
Mar 29 15:33:17 raspberry3 systemd[1]: Stopping LSB: start and stop MySQL...
Mar 29 15:33:17 raspberry3 mysql.server[21277]: MySQL server PID file could not be found! ... failed!
Mar 29 15:33:17 raspberry3 systemd[1]: Stopped LSB: start and stop MySQL.

$ sudo systemctl start mysql
pi@raspberry3:~/bin $ sudo systemctl status mysql
● mysql.server.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql.server)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2016-03-29 15:33:53 UTC; 1s ago
  Process: 21277 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql.server stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 21328 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql.server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 29 15:33:53 raspberry3 mysql.server[21328]: Starting MySQL
Mar 29 15:33:53 raspberry3 mysql.server[21328]: Couldn't find MySQL server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe) ... failed!
Mar 29 15:33:53 raspberry3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop MySQL.
```

`mysqld_safe` exists at `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`, so I've tried to copy it to the path `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe`, but that fails terribly.

Do I just need to adjust some path in some file so it may find `mysqld_safe` and it will start?

Thanks for any help getting MySQL running on the Raspberry!

/etc/init.d/mysql.server:
http://pastiebin.com/56fb184058ae8

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `/etc/init.d/mysql.server` is looking for MySQL in the wrong place. You are correct that copying the binary will cause problems.

One way to fix it would be to edit this file, and change occurrences of `/usr/` to `/usr/local/`. This is what I recommend.

Another would be to uninstall MySQL completely from `/usr/local` and install it in `/usr` instead (`./configure --prefix=/usr`). If you use this route, make sure you uninstall it completely, removing every file it installed.

Comment: Hi Will. Thanks for the pointer. What file do you recommend I change, exactly?

Comment: Open up `/etc/init.d/mysql.server` in your text editor and look for `/usr/` and replace it with `/usr/local/`. It might help if you post the contents of this file in your question and then I could tell you more specifically.

Comment: HI Will, full file posted to pastiebin. See new edit in OP.